# node.js find name of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

im having a go at binance api. When i run the code below:

```
  binance.depth("BNBBTC", (error, depth, symbol) => {
  console.log(symbol+" market depth", depth.bids);
  });
```

it does what it is suppose to do, which is:

```
 '0.00110170': 30.69,
 '0.00110110': 5.44,
 '0.00110090': 80,
 '0.00110020': 2.72,
 '0.00110010': 457.37,
 '0.00110000': 148.59,
 '0.00109990': 448.62,
 '0.00109960': 5.05,
 '0.00109950': 3.28,
 '0.00109930': 65.92,
```

What i am trying to do is return the values on the right only (or save them as a variable.) The only thing is i dont know how to reference them, any help would be awesome, thankyou

Comment: Is that actually the output you get from your console.log?

Comment: BNBBTC market depth { '0.00110180': 145,
  '0.00110170': 30.69,
  '0.00110110': 5.44,
  '0.00110090': 80,
  '0.00110020': 2.72,
  '0.00110010': 457.37,

Comment: Use `Object.values(data)`  this will give you an array of the values.

Comment: ^ Even better than my approach. Worth noting for future use that Internet Explorer does not support `Object.values`

Comment: So it looks like you have a `depth` object with a `bids` value that is an object. So you can use `Object.values(depth.bids)` to get an array of the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that **depth.bids** have the form:

```
{ '0.00110180': 145, '0.00110170': 30.69, '0.00110110': 5.44 }
```

You can then traverse the keys and reference the values using the key:

```
for (var key in depth.bids) {
  console.log(depth.bids[key]);
}
```

Or use the Object.values:

```
console.log(Object.values(depth.bids));
```